# Covariant derivative/connection of a local frame $\nabla \bar e = \nabla(e)g + edg$

Tags: differential-geometry

> Suppose $e$ and $\bar e$ are two frames for a vector bundle $E \to M$ over $U \subset M$ such that $\bar e = eg$ for some $g: U \to \text{GL}(r,\Bbb R)$. Then $$\nabla \bar e = \nabla(e)g + edg.$$

I'm trying to understand this which is seemingly just the Leibniz rule, but I have some trouble with the definitions. A frame $e = (e_1,\dots,e_r)$ is an $r$-tuple of sections $e_i : U \to E$ such that $e(p)=(e_1(p),\dots,e_r(p))$ forms a basis for $E_{p}$.

There are some slight ambiguities here, first off is $e$ a map $e : U \to E$ also? I mean it has to be since otherwise $\nabla e$ would not make sense.  Second, could someone help me understand how the above equation is the Leibniz rule? In general for a connection $\nabla$ on a vector bundle the Leibniz rule gives $$\nabla (fs)=df \otimes s + f\nabla s$$ where $s$ is a section $M \to E$, but $f :M \to \Bbb R$ is a smooth function not a map with codomain $\text{GL}(r,\Bbb R)$ so what gives?

Answer (score 2):

So suppose we have a linear connection on a vector bundle $E$, then in any frame $(e_1,\dots, e_n)$, there exist one forms $\xi_i^j$ such that:
$$\nabla e_i=\xi_i^j\otimes e_j$$
Now suppose that $\tilde{e}_i$ is another frame, related by a matrix of smooth function $g=g^i_j$, such that $\tilde{e}_i=e_jg^j_i$, then:
\begin{align}
\nabla(\tilde{e_i})=&\nabla(e_jg^j_i)\\
=&\nabla(e_j)g^j_i+e_jdg^j_i
\end{align}
This is really what your formula is saying, they're just removing the indices as the statement holds for all $i$, so you can apply it to the frame $e=(e_1,\dots, e_n)$.

Comment: So $\nabla \bar e = \nabla(e)g + edg$ is not missing a tensor product $\nabla \bar e = \nabla(e)g + e \otimes dg$? @chris

Comment: @Tepes nope it’s just matrix multiplication

Answer (score 2):

What is a little confusing here is that the scalar multiplication is being written in the opposite of the standard order. In other words, given a real scalar $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and vector $v \in V$, the notation for scalar multiplication used here is
$$ vs \text{ instead of the usual }sv. $$
The reason for this is the following: First, a standard convention for matrices is to use the superscript as a row index and the subscript as a column index. Second the standard convention is to write the basis of a vector space using subscripts for the index. This means that you can write a basis $(e_1, \dots, e_r)$ of a vector space formally as a row matrix,
$$ e = \begin{bmatrix} e_1 & e_2 &\cdots & e_r \end{bmatrix}. $$ Then, any vector $v$ can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors. The coefficients $c = (c^1, \dots, c^r)$ are written using superscripts. This allows the formula for $v$ to be written formally as matrix multiplication:
$$ v = e_1c^1 + \cdots + e_rc^r = \begin{bmatrix} e_1 & \cdots & e_r \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} c^1 \\ \vdots \\ c^r \end{bmatrix} = ec. $$
If $\bar{e}$ is another basis, then since each $\bar{e}_j$ is a vector, there exist coefficients $g_j^i$ such that
$$ \bar{e}_j = e_1g^1_j + \cdots + e_rg^r_j. $$
In other words, $g$ is an invertible matrix such that
$$ \bar{e} = eg. $$

If you have a vector bundle and $e$ and $\bar{e}$ are frames, then the formulas above at each fiber $E_x$ gives you
$$ \bar{e} = eg, $$
where $g$ is now a matrix of scalar functions. This is really a system of $r$ equations of the form
$$ \bar{e}_j = e_1g^1_j + \cdots + e_rg^r_j. $$

If you now take the covariant derivative of each side of this equation, you get by the product rule,
$$ \nabla\bar{e}_j = \nabla e_1 g^1_j + \cdots + \nabla e_r g^r_j + e_1dg^1_j + \cdots e_r dg^r_j. $$
This can be written in matrix form as
$$ \nabla\bar{e} = (\nabla e)g + e(dg). $$

As you have already noted, there is no way to write $g$ directly in terms of $e$ and $\bar{e}$. It exists by the fact that $e$ and $\bar{e}$ are bases of a vector space (at each point in the manifold). As @psl2Z correctly observes, you can write $g$ in terms of $\bar{e}$ and the dual basis of $e$.

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$A guick comment about how a frame is equivalent to a trivialization. If you have a frame over $O \subset M$ then there is a diffeomorphism
\begin{align*} \Phi: O\times\R^r &\rightarrow E\\
(x,v) &\mapsto e_1(x)v^1+\cdots+e_r(x)v^r = ev \in E_x.
\end{align*}
The inverse map is a trivialization of $\pi^{-1}(O)$. Given another frame $\bar{e}$, you get another map
\begin{align*} \overline\Phi: O\times\R^r &\rightarrow E\\
(x,v) &\mapsto \bar{e}_1(x)v^1+\cdots+\bar{e}_r(x)v^r = \bar{e}v \in E_x.
\end{align*}
Since
$$ \bar{e}\bar{v} = eg\bar{v}, $$ The transition map between the two trivializations is
\begin{align*}
\Phi^{-1}\circ\overline{\Phi}: O\times\R^r &\rightarrow O\times\R^r\\
(x,\bar{v}) &\mapsto (x,g\bar{v}).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you this is very clearly written. I think I might be confusing $g$ with the transition maps as they should be given by $e^{-1}_i \circ e_j$ @deane

Comment: Good point. Turns out that there is an equivalence between a trivialization and a frame and $g$ really is the transition map. I'll add a few comments about that.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand $e$ as $e = (e_1,...,e_r)$ and $\nabla e = (\nabla e_1, ..., \nabla e_r)$ and $dg = (dg^i_j)$ as matrix. Then, with Einstein summation convention, $\bar e = e g = (g^i_1 e_i, ..., g^i_r e_i)$ and $\nabla \bar e_j = \nabla (g^i_j e_i) = (dg^i_j) e_i + g^i_j \nabla e_i$ and therefore $\nabla \bar e = e dg + (\nabla e )g$.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to write $g$ purely in terms of $e$ and $\bar e$? @psl2Z

Comment: Pointwise it is nothing but a change of basis. So, $g$ only depends on $e$ and $\bar e$.

Comment: I meant can I write something like $g = e^{-1}\bar{e}$, but I don't think it works since $e^{-1}$ doesn't mean anything if we think of $e$ as a row vector? @psl2Z

Comment: If one had the dual frame $\varepsilon = (\varepsilon^1,...,\varepsilon^r)$ of $e$ it would be $g^i_j = \varepsilon^i(\bar e_j)$, so $g = (\varepsilon^i(\bar e_j))$. But then you have to know the dual frame.